# How can I predict a function f(x) based on given data value pairs?

Tags: functions

I need to predict a function that can satisfy the value pairs given:

[Table of values here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QFON.png)

I tried plotting y against x, to see the graph shape and got something like this: 
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRzEN.png)

How can I come up with a function that fits this curve well? I'm thinking of a tangent function but it's cyclic and goes to infinity (on the y-axis) so that wouldn't really work.

Comment: Looks like a growth-sigma type of curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a [Sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). Or more specifically, a [Logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). You can manipulate the parameters to determine the min and max points.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Is it possible for me to adjust the bounds for the x-axis? for example if I want x from 0 to 600?

Comment: @Bei You will have to restrict it manually by truncating the graph.

Comment: Noted with thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

As Henry W. answered, you are looking for a logistic function, that is to say $$y=\frac L{1+e^{-k(x-x_0)}}$$ The model is highly nonlinear with respect to its parameters and the nonlinear regression you should use to get parameters $L,k,x_0$ will need some reasonable estimates.

What we know is that the upper asymptote is $L$; so, from the data $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
 0 & 0.090 \\
 18 & 0.102 \\
 78 & 0.124 \\
 142 & 0.253 \\
 205 & 0.487 \\
 255 & 1.020 \\
 322 & 1.980 \\
 378 & 3.950 \\
 446 & 5.880 \\
 504 & 6.760 \\
 564 & 7.200
\end{array}
\right)$$ assume $L\approx8$; similarly, searching in the table the $x$ such that $y\approx \frac L2$, you can estimate that $x_0\approx 400$. Now, rewrite the model $$\log\big(\frac Ly-1\big)=-k(x-x_0)$$ Using the previous estimates, the plot of the approximation gives a slope $k\approx 0.02$. At this point, you have all required estimates and you can start the nonlinear regression.

This should give more or less $$y=\frac{7.52898}{1+e^{-0.0168888 (x-374.131)}}$$ $R^2=0.999245$ showing a very good fit. This is also confirmed by the statiscal information related to the parameters $$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 x_0 & 374.131 & 4.48744 & \{363.52,384.742\} \\
 k & 0.0168888 & 0.000939502 & \{0.0146673,0.0191104\} \\
 L & 7.52898 & 0.161397 & \{7.14734,7.91063\} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Very interesting derivation. Thx for sharing.